# How to change sites for a question

Tags: discussion, support, migration, cross-posting

I am realizing that a question I posted to the Cryptography site may be better suited for the math se.  I do not want to add unnecessary clutter by posting a new question with the same problem on math se.  What should I do?

Question **migrated** [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166268/polyalphabetic-cipher-breaking-guessing-period-length-formula).

Comment: You can ask moderators of the Crypto site to migrate the question to this site. They may not honor the request for some reason (they will likely explain it to you). For example, the question may have received an answer that they think would be worth keeping in Crypto.SE. Opinions may vary whether that is a good reason - I just made one up :-)

Comment: If their opinion is that it is ok to repost the question here, then you can do so. Should that happen, then you should link both versions of the question to the other, so that answerers don't need to waste time reproducing something that has already been explained. You could also give a link to the question here. That way our users can take a look and weigh in.

Comment: In the specific case (no feedback yet) I'd delete it there, and reask it here.